# Looking for a way to verify email addresses using Swift and Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently looking for a solution for creating an iOS application using swift and Firebase as an authentication and database storage system. I'm relatively new to swift and Firebase. I currnently have methods in place that validate the input of my text, in the given text fields in a form.

Here is my method used to validate the format of the email. "Utilities" is in reference to a expression that shows the valid format.

```
let cleanedEmail = emailAddressTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if Utilities.isValidEmail(cleanedEmail) == false {

        return "Please enter a valid email address."
```

I'm looking to now "Verify" an email address in swift and firebase, and find a method or function to verify wether the email address given by a user on signup is real and not just given to support the format of the validation method I have created. This helps me prevent errors on input for users when they sign up.

Just to be clear, if I give a valid email address of "Jack@fmail.com" it will be accepted even if it isn't a real domain. Therefore if a user mistypes their email address it will create an account on a false domain.

If anyone has any suggestions,I'd be happy to hear them.

Thank you.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

Answer (score 0):

The most common used option is to send a verification mail to the user. You can activate that functionality in your Firebase console under the Authentication setting. See image and the link for more information on how to set it up in your app.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth

[image]